# How to reset the size of the Qt's window font?

Tags: qt, windows-10

I have left my computer on overnight and in the morning I have noticed, that the font of the windows in QtCreator is significantly bigger as it was, though not everywhere. The text editor, the menu and the side panels are shown with the usual font size (see the first screenshot). I have also noticed, that this change affects other Qt programs, as the Maintenance tool and QtLinguist.

**Legend:** `Red` - huge font, should be reset. `Green` - font is as it should be.

[image: QtCreator]

[image: QtCreator Settings]

[image: Qt Maintenance tool]

[image: QtLinguist]

The font size of all other installed programs is unchanged. Just in case I have checked the display settings of Windows and the scale is at 100%, where it was.

**Note:** I have tried deleting the settings under user/AppData..., but it didn't help.

How to reset the font back to normal?

Comment: It might be somehow related to Creator's automatic high dpi scaling screwing up (it's the option "Enable high DPI scaling" which is enabled on your creator). Usually, Creator's scaling seems to work quite ok on Windows (which is not true for Linux) but I have also seen exactly similar issue as you described at least once. If I remember right restarting Creator didn't help but restarting Windows helped...

Comment: @talamaki, Thank you for the comment! This is the second time it happens to me. The only "solution" to this issue, which worked for me, is to completely remove Qt and its data folders, and reinstall it. Next time I will try to either clear the Windows' temp files as well, or to restart the computer. In any case, it is a frustrating issue.

Answer (score 3):

for changing the size of the font in the source code you can use the short cuts (with the editor focused)

to zoom in: "ctrl" and  "+"

to zoom out: "ctrl" and  "-"

---

for the environment the you can set the environment variable

```
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5
```

Comment: _The text editor, the menu and the side panels are shown with the usual font size._

Comment: _export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5_ I am aware of that too. This zooms in/out the whole window. The relative size of the font in the areat, marked with red, remains unchanged.